# Android push notification icon

Tags: android, push-notification, icons

Normally I use my application's icon in my push notifications.

```
.setSmallIcon(applicationContext.getApplicationInfo().icon)
```

How can I use a different custom icon (that I created myself) in a different push notification?

Answer (score 0):

```
 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.your_icon)
```

[image]

Comment: How do I place my icon in the drawable namespace?

Answer (score 0):

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
        .setContentText(notificationMessage)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.YOUR_IMAGE)
        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setStyle(bigStyle);

NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationmanager.notify(nofy_id, builder.build());
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I place my icon in the drawable namespace?

Comment: just add your icon in drawable folder